# Windows Server 2008 DNS resolver problem (NXDOMAIN answers)

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I've got a strange problem with our Windows Server 2008 DNS answering requests with a NXDOMAIN for valid domain names. After flushing the cache I get the valid answer. As this machine is our primary domain controller I cannot give login access to lots of people if they have problems with the DNS service.

The server is patched, rebooted and up2date ... and Im kind of lost.

Comment: You need more in your question.  What are the domain names?  How do you know that they are valid?  What does your [DNS server debug log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753579.aspx) say that the server is doing when this happens?

Comment: Im sorry, when I wrote these lines I was in a hurry. Im not quite sure about the domain name, it was something with the .biz tld. I've got a server running bind which could resolve the IP address for the domain. But thanks for the hint with the debug log!

Comment: Ok, today we had the same problem again with debug logging activated. I see the request in the log: "14.07.2011 11:08:00 0580 PACKET  0000000004486330 UDP Rcv 192.168.1.153 ed8d Q [0001 D NOERROR] A (3)www(3)uol(3)com(2)br(0)". Then follows the answer section: "ed8d R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] A     (3)www(3)uol(3)com(2)br(0)". Ill have to look for a detailed description of the log details. currently I see no real hint for an explanation. I solved the problem by deleting the .br section from the cache and everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

If these are external domains, and your server is configured to use forwarders, I would suggest using different forwarders or using root hints instead of forwarders.

Comment: Yes, these are external domains and we do not use any forwarders. The root hints are in place and in use.